# I use lattice in R but meet an error with "layout"

Tags: r, lattice

The code is:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)
f <- rep(0:1, each = 50)
y <- x + f - f*x + rnorm(100, sd = 0.5)
f <- factor(f, labels = c("Group1", "Group2"))
xyplot(y~x | f, layout(2,1))
```

The error is:

```
Error in layout(2, 1) : layout matrix must contain at least one reference
to each of the values {1 ... 2}
```

I do not know why I get this error. I just copy these codes from one online course about R. In the video of that course, the teacher make graphs successfully with these codes.

Comment: `layout=c(2,1)` . If you look at the examples at the bottom of `?xyplot` you will see examples of its use.

Comment: You are not giving a matrix argument to layout.